# Ouput Expression Strings with Fully Qualified Enum Values in C#

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

It seems that LINQ Expression Trees don't express Enum values as fully qualified when .ToString() is called. Here is the current code:

```
BinaryExpression exp = stringsEqual; /* e.g. '(s1, s2) => s1 == s2' */

MethodInfo method =
    typeof(string).GetMethod("Equals", new[] { typeof(string), typeof(StringComparison) });

ConstantExpression comparison =
    Expression.Constant(StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase, typeof (StringComparison));

MethodCallExpression caseInsensitiveEquals = Expression.Call(exp.Left, method, exp.Right, comparison);

Console.WriteLine(caseInsensitiveEquals); // will call .ToString()
```

- **Result**: `(s1, s2) => s1.Equals(s2, OrdinalIgnoreCase)`
- **Expected**: `(s1, s2) => s1.Equals(s2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`

This expression itself may execute, but the string is not a valid expression if run through an expression parser.

What's the trick to getting an Expression to output fully-qualified Enum values?

Comment: What you're seeing is the *debug* output, ignore it as it's not meant to produce C# code anyway (it just calls `ToString` on the constant value). The expression is valid.

Comment: _"What's the trick to getting a ConstantExpression to fully qualify an Enum value?"_ -- please provide a clear example of what you mean? As Lucas explains, the expression itself has the correct value. In what scenario is this not good enough? Please show some code that does not work, so that someone can provide an answer that fixes whatever problem it is you actually have. (If your only problem is that you simply misunderstood the debug output and there is no actual problem, please consider deleting the question).

Comment: I have updated the question to make it clearer that I am actually interested in the string output.

Comment: What expression parser are you using? Running the string ouput doesn't seem like a good idea. Or do you mean you are trying to run the actual expression against `linq-to-entities`, if that is the case, it would fail because `L2E` doesn't support  string comparison enum

Answer (score 2):

Looking in ILSpy, `Expression.ToString()` contains a single line:

```
return ExpressionStringBuilder.ExpressionToString(this);
```

`ExpressionStringBuilder` is an internal, sealed class. If you want to hack it bad enough, grab that from ILSpy or some other source and hack as you would like.

Comment: Why use ILSpy when [you can just get it from the open source CoreFX repo](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/41e203011152581a6c65bb81ac44ec037140c1bb/src/System.Linq.Expressions/src/System/Linq/Expressions/ExpressionStringBuilder.cs)?

Comment: Old habits. :) Thanks for posting the source link.